# How to monitor Nagios?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have implemented Nagios. But I like to monitor Nagios itself. I don't want to have another nagios to monitor this Nagios. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up some simple hearbeat monitoring for your nagios.. just to make sure that your nagios is up and you get notified in case nagios server itself is not running... http://docs.alertagility.com/guide/heartbeat/

Comment: Yes this looks good. I tried it and it works nice for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install Nagios plugin and enable the configuration for local host.

follow any of the documentation of the nagios installation that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

A program that does something to its own has to be AI. So technically this is impossible. You can check through nagios the localhost but in case of any problem you will not be notified. If nagios goes down, notifications can not be sent.